# shiny fileinput, client file upload automatically by session info

Tags: r, shiny

I am making a Shiny server app.

I would like to add a local file path to the url session information and then automatically upload the file when the session starts.

Do I need to know about javascript to do this?

If you know how, thank you for your help.